# Reverse engineering with hibernate on a maven project using MySQL

Tags: mysql, hibernate, maven

I am trying to apply reverse engineering with hibernate on a maven project using MySQL as a data base, I allredy installed the jBOSS from the market place and configuration properties are successfully created by I have problem with the java.lang.runtimeexception java.lang.reflect.invocationtargetexc

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please provide full stack trace, code related to the problem.

Comment: I added a screen picture in the subject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this problem is due with the missing of dependencies of your maven project to resorve that try to add those dependencies in your project

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate3</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.3.GA</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.9</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: What does JUnit have to do with this problem?

Comment: Thank you for your replay, the problem was in the hibernate artifactId i wrote it wrong, thank you again